# SSIS expression to SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl

I am trying to convert "Derived Columns" Expressions to SQL statements to be able to add and replace column values and names.

I am having some issues in finding the correct help to understand nested formulas in SSIS.

Formula i have in SSIS is,

```
[A] == 0 || ISNULL([A]) ? -1 :  [A]
```

How do i write this in a SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing like this

```
CASE WHEN [A] = 0 OR [A] IS NULL THEN -1  ELSE [A] END
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick respons!

Comment: In sql server you have to use `[A] = 0` instead of `[A] == 0`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql#examples

Comment: @Hadi Yo bro ;p

Comment: @DL1 if this answer solved your problem you have to mark it as correct. Just click on the mark below the voting arrows. Also if you find an answer useful it is good to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ISNULL()` function

```
CASE ISNULL([A],0) WHEN 0 THEN -1 ELSE [A] END
```

Or

```
CASE WHEN [A] IS NULL THEN 0
           WHEN [A] = 0 THEN 0
           ELSE [A] END
```